# for to-many relationship: property =; desired type = NSSet; given type

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

i am try to add value in core data. but after click on submit button app is crash and show me error like:

> for to-many relationship: property = "roshan"; desired type = NSSet;
>   given type = Unique; value =  (entity: Unique;
>   id: 0x60800022fd60
>    ; data:
>   {
>       abc =     (
>       );
>       number = nil;
>       study = nil; }).'

```
- (IBAction)submitData:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];
    Resgistration *newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    //newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Unique *number = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unique" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //number = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unique" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [number setValue:_numberText.text forKey:@"number"];
    [number setValue:_studyText.text forKey:@"study"];
    NSMutableSet *roshanSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [roshanSet addObject:number];
    [newContact addRoshan:roshanSet];
    [newContact setValue:number forKey:@"roshan"];
    [newContact setValue:_numberText.text forKey:@"number"];
    [newContact setValue:_nameText.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newContact setValue:_addressText.text forKey:@"address"];
    [newContact setValue:_emailText.text forKey:@"email"];
    [newContact setValue:_othernoText.text forKey:@"otheNo"];
    [newContact setValue:_hobbyText.text forKey:@"hobby"];
    [newContact setValue:_contactText.text forKey:@"contact"];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];

    _nameText.text = @"";
    _addressText.text = @"";
    _emailText.text = @"";
    _othernoText.text = @"";
    _hobbyText.text = @"";
    _contactText.text = @"";
    _numberText.text = @"";

    TableViewController *table = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What if you get rid of this: `[newContact setValue:number forKey:@"roshan"];`?  It seems you're trying to overwrite your set value with a number.

Comment: Hey, number is my second entity object & newContact is my first my entity and roshan is relationship name between them. [newContact setValue:number forKey:@"roshan"]; assign foreign key.

Comment: "roshan" can't be both a single number and a set of them at the same time.  Since it's to-many, you need the set, not the individual object.

Comment: hey, thanks for reply but this problem is solve can you help in other question posted by me 1 hour ago check it @Phillip Mills.